# Where to find missing Python API/Documentation for a module on Github?

Tags: python, api, documentation

I'm fairly new to Python and I'm trying to get my head around documentation of modules saved to Github.

My case is module SimpSOM (https://github.com/fcomitani/SimpSOM). I installed the module and attempted the basic intro example presented on the Github page and in the linked readthedocs page.

Unfortunately, I immediately run into problems with:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import SimpSOM as sps
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

#training
net = sps.somNet(20, 20, raw_data, PBC=True)
```

Which returns the error:

```
NameError: name 'raw_data' is not defined
```

I do not think *raw_data* is not part of the SimpSOM module, it may just be a place holder name for the sack of example and I can't find any mention of raw_data in the corresponding websites/documentation. However, Google revealed the following page: https://pydoc.net/SimpSOM/1.3.1/SimpSOM/ with the following code:

```
class somNet:
    """ Kohonen SOM Network class. """

    def __init__(self, netHeight, netWidth, data, loadFile=None, PCI=0, PBC=0):

        """Initialise the SOM network.

        Args:
            netHeight (int): Number of nodes along the first dimension.
            netWidth (int): Numer of nodes along the second dimension.
            data (np.array or list): N-dimensional dataset.
            ....
```

I have several questions:

1. Did my tired eyes miss complete API docs?
2. I can see from the comments that *raw_data* is in fact *data* which is of type *np.array* or *list*. If a module is missing documentation, is there any way of programmatically making an enquiry of a class module or a function to see what data types are expected?
3. Worst a case scenario, how can I generate my own documentation from the comments inside that class? It looks like they're compatible with doxygen.